# How to prevent Windows 10 from writing to SSD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

Newly installed windows 10, upgraded to 2020H2. 16GB Ram on Intel i7.

Sitting there for 2 days without doing anything.

But Windows 10 still kept on writing to my SSD around 10 ~ 100+ kb / secs.

For 2 days it has already written > 50gb. That is insane. (for doing nothing other than installation and upgrade of windows 10)

I have just replaced my SSD (died slightly > 4 months of usage). So I do not wish this newly replaced unit having the same fate.

How can I stop Windows 10 from unnecessarily writing to my SSD?

Comment: You cannot turn off Windows writing to a disk but 50 GB seems like a lot (assuming Windows 10 is up to date. Where is the data that is being written to?

Comment: Resource monitor shows mainly writing to ``NTFS master file table`` and ``NTFS volume log``. Certainly I cannot turn off windows writing to disk, but I expect 0 or minimum when I am not doing anything. Just like Linux

Comment: I agree with you about the constant writing.  Is it still writing large quantities (nearly 24 hours later)?   Go into MSCONFIG and start with minimal (basic) services. Does this change the excessive writing?

Comment: After monitoring for another 2 days. The total bytes written is approximately 4.2GB / day. Sitting there without doing anything on a newly installed Win10 without any 3rd party applications.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on with your computer. 4 GB / day is 120GB a month, 1,440 GB / year. My Windows 10 machines are 4 years old. Have you got legacy software installed?  An early virus?   If you can, start fresh, install nothing but Windows and check.

Comment: It is a fresh installation after my previous SSD died as mentioned in my original post

Comment: No idea. I have this machine with one SSD and a desktop with two SSD drives.   Faulty drive perhaps?  I am running out of ideas.